# Atom interferometry,gravity and inertia: What can it measure that light interferometry can't?

Tags: gravitational-waves, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms, machs-principle, frame-dragging

What previously unexplored effects in gravity and inertia can be examined with atom interferometry in ways that hasn't already been done through light interferometry?

Can atom interferometry be used to measure gravitational waves like LIGO has done with light interferometry?

Can atom interferometry be used to measure effects like frame dragging?

Can atom interferometry be used to measure machian relationships and gravinertial field?

Comment: The closest to what you are asking are "quantum optics" experiments with Bose-Einstein condensates in microgravity. They test mainly the strong Einstein principle in interaction with the quantum world. See e.g. [MAIUS 1](https://www.research-in-germany.org/en/research-landscape/news/2017/01/2017-01-23-maius-1---first-bose-einstein-condensate-generated-in-space.html) or [QUANTUS](https://www.zarm.uni-bremen.de/research/space-science/experimental-gravitation-and-quantum-optics/projects/quantus.html) experiments. This is far from a complete answer so I am just posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't know much about an atom interferometer but according to Wikipedia: "Atom interferometers have many uses in fundamental physics including measurements of the gravitational constant, the fine-structure constant, the universality of free fall, and have been proposed as a method to detect gravitational waves.[1] They also have applied uses as accelerometers, rotation sensors, and gravity gradiometers."  Sources are available at Wikipedia.

Comment: Might as well just give the wiki reference since you're not adding anything to the answer.

Comment: No, here correctly copying the relevant info from the source. Link-only answers are deleted.